Hide/Show Add New button on sub grid based on condition in powerapps
I a looking for help on how to add condition to show or hide ribbon buttons in a subgrid.
the condition is when the entity has a row already exists then  I need to hide the Add new ribbon button.
I am able to hide and show based on Form Values but i need to do so by looking at the row count of the entity,
